# When to use weighting in least squares?

Tags: least-squares, fitting, weighted-regression

Normally when one talks about weighted least squares, the end-goal is to weight each point by its variance.

However my question pertains to models which have multiple components. It will be easier to frame my question in the form of an example of some function. Let's say we have a large amplitude exponential decay, and at early times a smaller decaying sinusoidal signal is present added to the initial exponential:

$e^{-x/10} + e^{-x}*sin(x)$

Let's say I have data which extends out to x=20. Does this imply that I am "weighting" the slower exponential component more heavily? It has a factor of ~5-10 more points containing information about it compared to the sinusoidal component. My question is, is there some proof or conceptual argument which says that if one knows the model a priori, should the data be weighted such that the components of the model are weighted equally?

Comment: weighing is used to decrease the leverage of a certain point which would be having very high influence on the response curve/variable. Unless the points you mentioned here are outliers, which they aren't, why do you think they should be weighed any differently?

Comment: My intuition (and a problem I'm having with my current data) says that when you have noise on the order of one of the small amplitude components then the least squares could be minimized with some random fluctuation across the larger amplitude component. But if one knows where that small amplitude component should be a priori, shouldn't the weights of the datapoints be adjusted to force equal weighting of the model components with respect to minimization of least squares?

Comment: I think you can come up with conditional weights